# How to round a Unix/POSIX timestamp to the nearest 30-minutes?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, epoch

I want to take an epoch that is returned from a SQL query and round up (or down) 30 minutes. I want to do this on the second line of code. Any idea how to do so?

```
s = row.get("values")[0][1]
s = <<<round to closest 30 mins>>>
t = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(s)/1000.)
dateFmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
timeFmt = "%H:%M"
date = t.strftime(dateFmt)
time = t.strftime(timeFmt)
```

Comment: Divide by 30 minutes, round, and then multiply by 30 minutes again.

Comment: If your input is in seconds, then `s = round(s / 60 / 30) * 60 * 30`. But given your `/1000.`, maybe you have milliseconds? If so, `s = round(s/60/30/1000)*60*30*1000`.

Comment: That works!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First convert the data to your expected representation. This may involve timezone change. Assuming `t` is the representation you want, you can replace the elements you want:

```
# python 3
t.replace(minute=t.minute // 30 * 30, second=0, microsecond=0)
# python 2
t.replace(minute=t.minute / 30 * 30, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

I wouldn't use the solution from the comment about manipulating the timestamp itself, unless you're sure that it will always be in local timezone. You can run into issues with shifts by odd number of minutes (there are both `+xx30` and `+xx45` timezones)